# how to pass id to serverside from jquery method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

code I have tried and failed. Somewhere something is missing...

```
$(".delete").click(function() 
{
    var db_id = $(this).attr("db_id");
    alert(db_id);
    $.post("ajax_inspection.php", {type: qrystrdelete,id: id},
    function(data)
    {
        // callback function gets executed
        $('#db_id').html(data);
        alert("Return data" + data);
    });
```

ajax.inspection.php contains:

```
<?php
include_once("inspection_query_fun.php");
if($_REQUEST['type'] == 'qrystrdelete')
$var_result = deleteslab($_REQUEST['id']); 
?>
```

inspection_query_fun.php contains del

```
<php
function deleteslab($PAR_Id)
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM ".CONTROL_REPORT_DETAILS." WHERE sb_slab_id=".db_escape($PAR_Id);
    db_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: You are missing the closing `});` from your click handler.

Comment: You are sendind id instead of db_id and see the answer about qutations

Comment: What is failing? Is there a Javascript error?

Comment: @jax you should accept an answer when your problem was solved. Read **FAQ**

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
$.post("ajax_inspection.php", {type: qrystrdelete,id: id}
```

to this:

```
$.post("ajax_inspection.php", {type: "qrystrdelete",id: db_id}
```

Comment: It looks as if `id: id` should be `id: db_id` too.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to do some editing in following lines:

```
 var db_id = $(this).attr("db_id");
       alert(db_id);
       $.post("ajax_inspection.php", {type: qrystrdelete,id: id},
```

Replace it with the following :

```
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
       $.post("ajax_inspection.php", {type: "qrystrdelete",id: id},
```

Hope this will work.